# Circumventing the lack of a leftToggle option for ListItem in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to put the toggle element on the other side, but the problem is that `listItem` according to the `Material-ui` documentation doesn't support a `leftToggle` option (the attribute `leftToggle` doesn't exist). Is there any way to do this?

I want to do put the toggler and secondary text on the same line. Also, is there a solution that doesn't involve `ListItem`?

```
<ListItem primaryText={theEEState ? "Allow": "Disallow"}
          secondaryText="Allow / Disallow"
          rightToggle={
              <Toggle
                  onToggle={onToggleStateMethod}
                  toggled={theEEState}
              />
          }
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Toggle component. The documentation contains an example of a left hand side switch.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toggle

```
<Toggle
  label="Label on the right"
  labelPosition="right"
  style={styles.toggle}
/>
```